# DataGrid Button Column Not Appearing

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, datagrid

I have a column in my `DataGrid` that is set like this;

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="RAMs PDF" Width="*">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="Select RAMs PDF" Click="OnRAMsButtonClick"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

This displays a button in each row, but only when I click into the cell that contains the button. If the focus is not inside this cell then the `Button` does not appear. Here is what it looks like without clicking into the cell;

[image]

However, after clicking into the cell (twice) the `Button` appears;

[image]

How can I make it so A) the `Button` is visible without having to click inside the cell and B) the user only has to click on the cell once for the click event on the `Button` to trigger? (instead of the three currently, two to get the button appear, one to perform the click event.

Comment: The CellEditingTemplate is only displayed when editing the cell. You need to put the button into the DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the CellTemplate instead of CellEditingTemplate

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="RAMs PDF" Width="*">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="Select RAMs PDF" Click="OnRAMsButtonClick"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```